# RPI - WGET install/upgrade/update issue

Tags: osmc

I'm trying to install CUPS & I'm getting the below error.

```
osmc@osmc:~$ sudo apt install cups
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
osmc@osmc:~$
```

Hence, tried to update/upgrade, still same error. any guidance please?
Running base OS is OSMC with Transmission & PiHole running on the background.
Pihole isn't blocking anything, it's not able to get past the data in the card, not sure how can it even reach the network.

```
osmc@osmc:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
osmc@osmc:~$
```

please any help is much appreciated. I've tried searching but nothing is coming up with OSMC.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something wrong with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list`. Probably not a proper apt source file.

Delete it (or move it to a safe place) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list`:

```
$ sudo rm -r ./azlux.list
```

And update:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Ок.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.